# Is this a question about Cauchy's functional equation?

Tags: calculus

If $ f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$

$x≠0$
$y≠0$
which of following is possible?

A. $f(x)=\frac1x$

B. $f(x)=2x$

C. $f(x)=2^x$

D. $f(x)=\sin(2x)$

Comment: This is Jensen's functional equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try plugging in the functions given in A, B, C, D and see that only B will work. (For all $x, y$, of course)

Also, this is Jensen's functional equation. The solutions are linear functions or constant functions. Thus the answer is B.